# How to detect clicks on empty space via python?

Tags: python, interface

To elaborate - I want a setup where LMB clicking (in the LMB to select setup) on an empty space in the 3D View causes all of the mesh to be deselected when in Edit Mode, all objects when in Object mode, etc. I specifically would like to do it via an addon, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.. Do you just want to deselected everything (in python)?

Comment: I edited the question with a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually really simple:

- Go to *User Preferences > Input* and change the filter type from *Name* to *Key-Binding*
- Search for `action` and find the *3D View* category
- Change `view3d.cursor3d` to `object.select_all`
- Set *Action* to *Deselect*

---

- Clear search filter
- Expand *3D View > Mesh* and *Add New*
- Set it to `mesh.select_all` and *Deselect*
- Bind it to *Mouse*, *Action* and *Press*

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. I meant Select mouse (I think is the term). So - LMB clicking on empty space in the LMB to select setup, or RMB in the RMB to select.

Comment: I see, my bad! You can still make it work: bind the `select_all` operation to double-click so it doesn't interfere with LMB select click!